# Swift: Any Kind of sequence as a function parameter

Tags: swift, swift2, sequence

I have created my custom sequence type and I want the function to accept any kind of sequence as a parameter. (I want to use both sets, and my sequence types on it)

Something like this:

```
private func _addToCurrentTileset(tilesToAdd tiles: SequenceType)
```

**Is there any way how I can do it?**

It seems relatively straightforward, but I can't figure it out somehow. Swift toolchain tells me: 
`Protocol 'SequenceType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`, and I don't know how to create a protocol that will conform to SequenceType and the Self requirement from it.

I can eliminate the associatedType requirement with, but not Self:

```
protocol EnumerableTileSequence: SequenceType {
    associatedtype GeneratorType = geoBingAnCore.Generator
    associatedtype SubSequence: SequenceType = EnumerableTileSequence
}
```

Now if say I can eliminate self requirement, then already with such protocol definition other collectionType entities like arrays, sets won't conform to it.

Reference:
my custom sequences are all subclasses of enumerator type defined as:

```
public class Enumerator<T> {

    public func nextObject() -> T? {
        RequiresConcreteImplementation()
    }
}

extension Enumerator {

    public var allObjects: [T] {
        return Array(self)
    }
}

extension Enumerator: SequenceType {

    public func generate() -> Generator<T> {
        return Generator(enumerator: self)
    }
}

public struct Generator<T>: GeneratorType {

    let enumerator: Enumerator<T>
    public mutating func next() -> T? {
        return enumerator.nextObject()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler is telling you the answer: "*Protocol 'Sequence' can only be used **as a generic constraint** because it has Self or associated type requirements*".

You can therefore do this with generics:

```
private func _addToCurrentTileset<T: Sequence>(tilesToAdd tiles: T) {
    ...
}
```

This will allow you to pass in any concrete type that conforms to `Sequence` into your function. Swift will infer the concrete type, allowing you to pass the sequence around without lose type information.

If you want to restrict the type of the element in the sequence to a given protocol, you can do:

```
private func _addToCurrentTileset<T: Sequence>(tilesToAdd tiles: T)  where T.Element: SomeProtocol {
    ...
}
```

Or to a concrete type:

```
private func _addToCurrentTileset<T: Sequence>(tilesToAdd tiles: T)  where T.Element == SomeConcreteType {
    ...
}
```

If you don't care about the concrete type of the sequence itself (useful for mixing them together and in most cases storing them), then [Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458730/2976878) has got you covered with the type-erased version of `Sequence`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually care about the type of elements inside the sequence, is there some way to constrain a type of elements inside? 

something like: <T: SequenceType where T.Element: TileID>

Comment: @ambientlight Sure, you can do `<T:SequenceType where T.Generator.Element:TileID>` if `TileID` is a protocol or `== TileID` if it's a concrete type

Answer (score 4):

You can use type-eraser [`AnySequence`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_AnySequence_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Vs11AnySequence) for that:

> A type-erased sequence.
>
> Forwards operations to an arbitrary underlying sequence having the same `Element` type, hiding the specifics of the underlying `SequenceType`.

E.g. if you will need to store tiles as an internal property or somehow use its concrete type in the structure of you object then that would be the way to go.

If you simply need to be able to use the sequence w/o having to store it (e.g. just `map` on it), then you can simply use generics (like @originaluser2 suggests).  E.g. you might end up with something like:

```
private func _addToCurrentTileset<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Tile>(tilesToAdd tiles: S) {
    let typeErasedSequence = AnySequence(tiles) // Type == AnySequence<Tile>
    let originalSequence = tiles // Type == whatever type that conforms to SequenceType and has Tile as its Generator.Element
}
```